# Angular datasource in a kendo grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-grid

I'm using a kendo grid and i need to read datas from `NameOfMethod` defined in controller `NameOfController`.

Before the code was this:

```
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource  
    .Ajax()
    .PageSize(10)
    .Read(read => read.Action("NameOfMethod", "NameOfController"))
```

I have to replace this code in angular.

I tried this:

```
var data = new kendo.data.DataSource({        
    transport: {
      read: 
    },
    pageSize: 10
 });
```

In `read:` how can I replace the previous code(

```
.Read(read => read.Action("NameOfMethod", "NameOfController"))
```

Thank you so much guys!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You could probably get away with something like:

```
read : "/NameOfController/NameOfMethod"
```

more info here: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-transport.read